# missing return statement in main method

Tags: java, return

I am trying to compile a program and getting a error message: "acc_man.java:46: missing return statement" . I am creating two bank account under class acc_man, and the other class has all methods to be used by the main method. The private method under the class Bank_Account is to be used for passing parameter to the constructor.

The code is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class acc_man {
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {

Bank_Account sav_account = new Bank_Account ();
Bank_Account cr_account = new Bank_Account ();
BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader
(new InputStreamReader (System.in));

System.out.println ("Please choose Account: 1.Savings 2.Credit");
int acc_type = Integer.parseInt (stdin.readLine());

System.out.println ("What do you want to do: 1. Deposit 2. Withdraw ");
int tr_type = Integer.parseInt (stdin.readLine());

System.out.println ("Please enter amount");
int amount = Integer.parseInt (stdin.readLine());

if (acc_type < 2) 

  if (tr_type < 2)
  sav_account.deposit (amount);
  sav_account.print();

  if (tr_type > 1)
  sav_account.withdraw (amount);
  sav_account.print();

if (acc_type > 1)

  if (tr_type < 2)
  sav_account.deposit (amount);
  sav_account.print();

   if (tr_type > 1)
   sav_account.withdraw (amount);
   sav_account.print();

}// method main
}// class acc_man

class Bank_Account {

private int amount;
private int balance;

public int Bank_Account (int initial_balance) {

balance = initial_balance;
}
// end constructor

public int deposit (int amount) {

balance = balance + amount;

return balance;
}
//end method deposit

public  int withdraw (int amount) {

balance = balance - amount;
return balance;
}

//end method withdraw

private int set_balance (int initial_balance) {

initial_balance = balance;
return initial_balance;
 }

// end method set_balance

public void print() {

System.out.println ("Current balance of the account is:" + balance);
}


// end method print
}
//end class Bank_Account
```

Please advise with correction. Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Instead of just splattering your code into the textarea, make sure that it's separated by file and that you indicate **where the problem is**.

Comment: Could you please post the complete exception details

Answer (score 0):

Main method should be in a public class

```
public class acc_man {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
          // ........ your codes

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Constructors use the name of the class and have no return type.

Replace:
    public int Bank_Account (int initial_balance) {

```
balance = initial_balance;
}
// end constructor
```

With:

```
public Bank_Account (int initial_balance) {

balance = initial_balance;
}
// end constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

delete the int statement in your  constructor

```
public  Bank_Account (int initial_balance) {
     balance = initial_balance;
}
```

it's throwing it  because is parsed  like a normal method